# Issues in Python Class for retrieving sub-subfolders

Tags: python

I'm unsuccesfully trying to get a Python Function that, in form of Class, return the subfolder of a given folder.

My dataset folder is structured as follow:

```
    datasets 
        Actor1,
            emotion1
            emotion2
        Actor2
            emotion1
            emotion2
```

```
# setting class

class Folder:
    """Attempt to model typical folder."""
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def get_folder(self):
        sep_ = os.path.sep
        files = glob.glob(sep_.join([self.path, "*"]))
        dir_list = list()

        for dir_ in files:
            if os.path.isdir(dir_) == True:
                dir_list.append(dir_)
        return dir_list
```

My issue is this:

`Folder(path).get_folder()` returns a list holding only the element in datasets directory

```
Out[8]: 
[..\\datasets\\Actor1',
 '..\\datasets\\Actor2']
```

But my required output is:

```
['...\\datasets\\Actor1\\emotion1',
 '...\\datasets\\Actor1\\emotion2',
 '...\\datasets\\Actor2\\emotion2',
 '...\\datasets\\Actor2\\emotion2',]
```

Could you help?

Comment: Don't know why but `test = os.listdir(Folder(path).get_folder())[0]` return the first element of my sub-subfolder but when I call `for t in os.listdir(test): print(t)`, returns error `TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not list.`

Comment: Well that's another issue, but `test` is a list, you can't call `os.list_dir(some_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
import glob


class Folder:
    """Attempt to model typical folder."""

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def get_folder(self):
        files = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.path, "*"))
        dir_list = []

        for f in files:
            if os.path.isdir(f):
                dir_list = dir_list + [
                    os.path.join(self.path, elt) for elt in os.listdir(f)
                ]
        return dir_list


print(Folder(".").get_folder())
```

Comment: Thanks @Be Chiller Too!
This returns only the sub-sub directories.
i.e. `['emotion1', 'emotion2', 'emotion1', 'emotion2']`
how could I join them with the path?

Comment: os.path.join(folder, file), I updated my answer